# Why do people sometimes apologize when there is no need to?

Tags: politeness

An example that comes to mind would be

```
I'm sorry, I just don't agree with you.
```

There are better examples which I can't remember at the moment.

Comment: This seems to be a good question for a 'Miss Manners' style site (it's not particularly a language thing).

Comment: I think there is much that could be said about this linguistically. The use of apologetic phrases as disjuncts indicating modality in English, for example, is sure to pop up in some linguistic treatise.

Comment: @Cerberus: do you think it's a linguistic issue? I would rather say it's politeness.

Comment: Besides @Cerberus’s point, another EL&U aspect: the word *sorry* can mean other things besides an apology — it can also be just an expression of regret, for instance, which is I think a helpful way to parse examples like the OP’s.

Comment: @nico: It is both, I think. The form of a linguistic utterance is usually best studied in conjunction with its content. Separating them is often a weakness.

Comment: @PLL: Good point. If it gets reopened you can post an answer... I remember once offering my condolences to an American women by saying "I'm sorry" in chat, to which she replied, "it's not your fault". I concluded I had misinterpreted this use of "I'm sorry" that I thought I had observed elsewhere, but it turned out she was just a bit absent minded.

Comment: @Cerberus: actually, I’ve had that very same exchange with several American friends!  I think the use of “I’m sorry” for sympathy/condolences may be more widespread in BrE than AmE — though I certainly know at least a couple of Americans who do use it.

Comment: Although it can be sarcasm, I believe that in most instances it reflects a subtle expression of compassion.  Observing the "tone of voice" plays an important role in better understanding what is intended.

Comment: @PLL: Oh! That is funny, I've never thought of it as a regional difference. Now that you mention it, this usage makes me think of Yes Minister. I seem to recall an episode where Sir Humphrey has just been bashing the LSE, as usual; the Minister protests, "but I went to the LSE!", whereupon Bernhard says, "oh, I'm so sorry".

Comment: @Cerberus As PLL and Randolf point out, this often expresses compassion or regret, but it [drives some other people nuts](http://xkcd.com/945/) (obligatory xkcd reference).

Comment: @Aed: Haha, nice.